# Define list of dictionaries based on jinja conditionals in an ansible role

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm creating an ansible role and I want to define my defaults in the following manner as an example:

```yaml
include_mas_mount: false
include_log_mount: false

mounts:
  - name: 1st default mount
    mountdir: /data/mount1
    nasdir: /vol1/mount1
  - name: 2nd default mount
    mountdir: /data/mount2
    nasdir: /vol1/mount2
{% if include_mas_mount %}
  - name: mas mount
    mountdir: /data/mas_mount
    nasdir: /vol1/mas_mount
{% endif %}
{% if include_log_mount %}
  - name: log mount
    mountdir: /data/log_mount
    nasdir: /vol1/log_mount
{% endif %}
```

In testing this role I get a jinja templating error. Is this sort of thing possible? Or does it have be done differently. The idea with the role is that the `include_mas_mount` and `include_log_mount` variables would be overridden by a host or group override.

The role is expected to loop over the `mounts:` list of dictionaries and create the defined mounts on the target device.

Comment: It was pretty obvious for this one, but for future questions, please don't stop your description after typing `I get a jinja templating error`. Give the precise error you get as well as the tasks/playbook/command/... you used to get that error. In other words, provide a [mre]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickfix the above by slightly changing your `mounts` definition:

```yaml
mounts: |-
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  - name: 1st default mount
    mountdir: /data/mount1
    nasdir: /vol1/mount1
  - name: 2nd default mount
    mountdir: /data/mount2
    nasdir: /vol1/mount2
  {% if include_mas_mount %}
  - name: mas mount
    mountdir: /data/mas_mount
    nasdir: /vol1/mas_mount
  {% endif %}
  {% if include_log_mount %}
  - name: log mount
    mountdir: /data/log_mount
    nasdir: /vol1/log_mount
  {% endif %}
  {% endfilter %}
```

Meanwhile, this is not the best approach for at least 2 reasons:

- You are using a 'complex' template for a variable definition when it is not needed nor justified and we tend to avoid this in ansible when possible.
- You define `mounts` in `defaults/main.yml` although (from your description) you do not want users to override that variable directly.

The following will give the exact same result fixing the above problems. I used the name `my_role` for the role

First, we keep in `roles/my_role/defaults/main.yml` only the variables which will be user overridable:

```yaml
---
include_mas_mount: false
include_log_mount: false
```

Then we create the following `roles/my_role/vars/main.yml` which contains roles variables we do not want users to play with:

```yaml
---
mas_mount:
  name: mas mount
  mountdir: /data/mas_mount
  nasdir: /vol1/mas_mount

log_mount:
  name: log mount
  mountdir: /data/log_mount
  nasdir: /vol1/log_mount

default_mounts:
  - name: 1st default mount
    mountdir: /data/mount1
    nasdir: /vol1/mount1
  - name: 2nd default mount
    mountdir: /data/mount2
    nasdir: /vol1/mount2

mounts: "{{ default_mounts
  + ([log_mount] if include_log_mount | bool else [])
  + ([mas_mount] if include_mas_mount | bool else []) }}"
```

*In the above, the use of `bool` is a best practice to make sure the value is interpreted as a boolean as users may override your variable with content that otherwise translates to a string (like e.g. when using a `vars_prompt`)*

For the tests, I created the following dummy `roles/my_role/tasks/main.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Debug mounts var
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: mounts
```

and ran the role from the following `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Test my conditional list in role
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - name: my_role
    - name: my_role
      vars:
        include_mas_mount: true
    - name: my_role
      vars:
        include_log_mount: true
    - name: my_role
      vars:
        include_mas_mount: true
        include_log_mount: true
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Test my conditional list in role] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [my_role : Debug mounts var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mounts": [
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount1",
            "name": "1st default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount1"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount2",
            "name": "2nd default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount2"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [my_role : Debug mounts var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mounts": [
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount1",
            "name": "1st default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount1"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount2",
            "name": "2nd default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount2"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mas_mount",
            "name": "mas mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mas_mount"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [my_role : Debug mounts var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mounts": [
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount1",
            "name": "1st default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount1"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount2",
            "name": "2nd default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount2"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/log_mount",
            "name": "log mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/log_mount"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [my_role : Debug mounts var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mounts": [
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount1",
            "name": "1st default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount1"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mount2",
            "name": "2nd default mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mount2"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/log_mount",
            "name": "log mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/log_mount"
        },
        {
            "mountdir": "/data/mas_mount",
            "name": "mas mount",
            "nasdir": "/vol1/mas_mount"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of all mounts

```yaml
  mounts_all:
    default:
      - name: 1st default mount
        mountdir: /data/mount1
        nasdir: /vol1/mount1
      - name: 2nd default mount
        mountdir: /data/mount2
        nasdir: /vol1/mount2
    mas:
      - name: mas mount
        mountdir: /data/mas_mount
        nasdir: /vol1/mas_mount
    log:
      - name: log mount
        mountdir: /data/log_mount
        nasdir: /vol1/log_mount
```

and a dictionary to include mounts

```yaml
    include_mounts:
      default: true
      mas: false
      log: true
```

Then, declare the list *mounts*

```yaml
  mounts: "{{ include_mounts|dict2items|
              selectattr('value')|map(attribute='key')|
              map('extract', mounts_all)|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  mounts:
  - mountdir: /data/mount1
    name: 1st default mount
    nasdir: /vol1/mount1
  - mountdir: /data/mount2
    name: 2nd default mount
    nasdir: /vol1/mount2
  - mountdir: /data/log_mount
    name: log mount
    nasdir: /vol1/log_mount
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    include_mounts:
      default: true
      mas: false
      log: true

    mounts_all:
      default:
        - name: 1st default mount
          mountdir: /data/mount1
          nasdir: /vol1/mount1
        - name: 2nd default mount
          mountdir: /data/mount2
          nasdir: /vol1/mount2
      mas:
        - name: mas mount
          mountdir: /data/mas_mount
          nasdir: /vol1/mas_mount
      log:
        - name: log mount
          mountdir: /data/log_mount
          nasdir: /vol1/log_mount

    mounts: "{{ include_mounts|dict2items|
                selectattr('value')|map(attribute='key')|
                map('extract', mounts_all)|flatten }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: mounts
```

Comment: I really like this answer and it's explained very well.  I had to mark the answer from @Zeitounator as the answer because I felt it was a bit more thorough. It includes a solution to what I was attempting to do but also provides the best practice solution to accomplish my main objective.  I think both solutions are great though.  Thank you so much for the time you spent answering my question.